# Keeping props bound when sending them in a click event in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

We have a component that is being sent to a function and then rendered elsewhere in react.js. This is for the ability to open a slider with given content. We give that child component the props from the parent and all is well when we first load of course, but we need to be watching for state changes. For example:

```
<Contact
  handleNew={() => globalSlider.openContentSlider({
    content: <PersonalContactDetail _flags={_flags} />
  })}
/>
```

Of course the _flags is set appropriately on open, but the state changes do not cascade through.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A property on the Contact component needs to be updated, otherwise it won't re-render (and therefore can't re-render your PersonalContactDetail). I don't know your architecture of course, but perhaps you can pass the _flags into your Contact component, and then pass them back into your handleNew() handler as an argument....

```
<Contact flags={_flags}
  handleNew={(flagArgs) => globalSlider.openContentSlider({
    content: <PersonalContactDetail _flags={flagArgs} />
  })}
/>
```

... somewhere inside Contact:

```
if (this.props.handleNew) {
  this.props.handleNew(this.props.flags);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to pass an arrow function returning flags instead of returning the flags directly

Comment: Tried that, no joy :(

Comment: ok, sorry, for the wrong answer, can you include how the flags are defined in parent and how are they consumed in the client?